# Getting negative value(-1) when Byte write over server through socket programming in MAC OSX

Tags: objective-c, macos, osx-snow-leopard

I am trying to write bytes over server by using this function :

```
        case NSStreamEventHasSpaceAvailable:

           - - - - -  - -
           - - -  - - -  -
          --- - -  - -  --

        NSInteger   bytesWritten;
        bytesWritten = [self.oStream write:[self.data5 bytes] maxLength:[self.data5 length]];
        if (bytesWritten <= 0) {

            NSLog(@"No Byte written");
        } else {
           NSLog(@" Byte written");
            [self.data5 replaceBytesInRange:NSMakeRange(0, bytesWritten) withBytes:NULL length:0];
            space = YES;
        }
```

Here it is shown that bytes are written while when in the case

```
case NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable:

NSLog(@"Bytes available");


            NSInteger   bytesRead;
            NSUInteger  bufferLength;

            bufferLength = [ inputBuffer length];
            if (bufferLength == self.inputBufferCapacity) {
                NSLog(@"Error");
            } else {
                // Temporarily increase the size of the buffer up to its capacity 
                // so as to give us a space to read data.

                [self.inputBuffer setLength:self.inputBufferCapacity];

                // Read the actual data and respond to the three types of return values.

                bytesRead = [iStream read:((uint8_t *) [self.inputBuffer mutableBytes]) + bufferLength maxLength:self.inputBufferCapacity - bufferLength];
```

Here i am getting negative value in bytesRead. Please help me out where i am lacking in the code.

Answer (score 0):

A negative number means there was an error on the stream.  It could be anything really.  If you do

```
NSError* anError = [iStream streamError];
NSLog(@"Error = %@", anError);
```

You might be given a clue about what went wrong.